# How to get selected string from password in input for login?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, passwords

I have a login page where I have to input password like below example:
 username : abc password : 123456789

password will always being of 9 digits. Now for login user have to
 input 1st, 3rd and 8th string from password. and every time when user
 will reload page that 3 strings should be different. like if now its
 1st,3rd,8th after some time on load it will differ 2nd,9th,5th.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'conn.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql = 'SELECT name,pass,pin from `emp` where `name` = "'.$name.'" AND pass = "'.$pass.'" AND pin = "'.$pin.'" ';
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    if ($data) {
        header('Location: home.php');
        echo 'success';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Fail';
    }
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    Username:
     <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    Pin:
     <input type="password" name="pin" value="">
    Password:
     <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder='1st' value="">
     <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder='5th' value="">
     <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder='7th' value="">
     <button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

how can be achieve this.

Comment: Now, what's wrong with your code? What is the question?

Comment: Make your question clear. Nothing understand.

Comment: Why are you asking for three passwords?

Comment: @hungrykoala: he's asking for 3 chars from the user's password. The reason I don't know.

Comment: @hungrykoala yes your right. how to achieve this

Comment: i want this for better security

Comment: Hi, we will not write your code for you.  Have you tried something?  What you could do is randomly select 3 numbers between 1 and 9 and ask for these digits.  And then compare there 3 digits to the stored password.  But that would imply you stored the password in clear text which is not good practice.  Better to store the password encrypted, in a way that cannot be decrypted.  Then when a user enters his password, you encrypt again and compare encrypted versions.  But that would break what you want to do...  Dubious feature IMHO.

Comment: Just like as @Nic said it's an unnecessary feature. though it can be achieved. It will just be a nuisance for the user since they will take a longer time to login to your application. It would be better if you encrypt the passwords correctly and ask for the user's email address or birthday than to have them count their password and match in on the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help you. I used random unique numbers to define the fields and the `SUBSTR` function from mysql to identify the records.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'conn.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
    $pass3 = $_POST['pass3'];
    $char1 = $_POST['char1'];
    $char2 = $_POST['char2'];
    $char3 = $_POST['char3'];

    $sql = 'SELECT name,pass,pin from `emp` '
            . 'where `name` = "'.$name.'" '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(pass, '.$char1.', 1) = \''.$pass1.'\' '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(pass, '.$char2.', 1) = \''.$pass2.'\' ' 
            . 'AND SUBSTR(pass, '.$char3.', 1) = \''.$pass3.'\' '
            . 'AND pin = "'.$pin.'" ';
    echo $sql;


    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    if ($data) {
        header('Location: home.php');
        echo 'success';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Fail';
    }

}

// generate unique, not equal numbers
$char_pos = range(1, 9);
shuffle($char_pos);
$char_pos = array_slice($char_pos, 0, 3);
sort($char_pos)

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="char1" value="<?php echo $char_pos[0]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="char2" value="<?php echo $char_pos[1]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="char3" value="<?php echo $char_pos[2]; ?>">
    Username:
     <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    Pin:
     <input type="password" name="pin" value="">
    Password:
     <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder='<?php echo $char_pos[0]; ?>st' value="">
     <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder='<?php echo $char_pos[1]; ?>th' value="">
     <input type="password" name="pass3" placeholder='<?php echo $char_pos[2]; ?>th' value="">
     <button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```